# Inserting a HorizontalRule into a Google Doc with Python

Tags: google-docs-api

I can't find a function in the Python Google Docs API that can insert a HorizontalRule.

I tried using the "Try this method" window in the documentation pages to find a property that allows for insertion of a HorizontalRule, but I was unable to find one.